# How to include a separate file inside bootstrap.php that is meant for application wide constants and other application-wide Configure::write values?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP3.

I prefer to put my application-wide PHP constants and `Configure::write` values inside a separate php file, usually called `constants.php`

And then at the end of the `bootstrap.php`, I will include this `constants.php` file.

I have no problems with the PHP constants. However, I have issues using `Configure::write` inside this separate file.

Is there a way to use `Configure::write` in a separate php file? I have tried using

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;
```

inside `constants.php` but I still get errors.

**EDIT**

Example of `constants.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * provide all the kinds of site ID
 */
Configure::write('ADMINISTRATOR_SIDEBAR', array(
    'quotations' => [
        'link' => '/quotations',
    ],
    'projects' => [
        'sub_menu' => [
            [
                'title' => 'Project 1',
                'icon' => '',
                'link' => '/job_projects/view/5',
            ]
        ],
        'link' => '/job_projects'
    ]
));
```

When I write that and then

`require __DIR__ . '/constants.php';`

in the last line of `bootstrap.php`

I get

```
Error: Class 'Configure' not found 
File ...constants.php 
Line: 8
```

When I then added `use Cake\Core\Configure;` at the top of `constants.php`, the error is removed.

Does this mean my issue is solved?

Comment: And what is the error that you get?

Comment: Updated my question with error message. though I have become more interested in burzum answer about using class constants instead.

Comment: Yes adding `use Cake\Core\Configure;` is the right solution to your problem

Answer (score 1):

Do you have that many constants? Use class constants instead:

```
class UserType {
    const ADMIN = 'admin';
    const USER = 'user';
}
```

IMO it is better to keep them organized in classes than having tons of global constants. I dislike constants most of the time because you can't really never ever change them at run time. So this leaves just two use cases for them:

1. Things that should *never ever* change at runtime (which is rare)
2. Using them for "identifiers" instead of strings

Explaining 2. a little more: `$userRole === 'admin'` can fail because of a typo, you won't get an error and might end up with a pretty shitty to debug situation while doing `$userRole === UserRole::ADMIN` will throw an error if it is not present.

You're not showing any code, so no idea what you're doing wrong with Configure. Why are you not simply using [Configure::load()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Core.Configure.html#_load)  and the `$config = []' array in the file you're going to load with that method?

Comment: You are right. I tend to use constants and Configure for identifiers like the example you gave. I will try to move as many of these into class constants as much as possible. On the rare case, I do have constants that are never ever change, should I use Configure? and if so, can I declare in a separate php file?

Comment: Sure you can use a separate file.

Comment: I have edited the question to add an example of what I wrote in the separate php file. I have not a clue what you mean by `Configure::load` and `$config = []`. Can you give an example in your answer?

Comment: One more clarification: when you say use class constants. where are these classes? Are they located in for e.g. `Lib` folder and have no functions or properties except purely for constants, and have nothing to do with Model classes?

Comment: If you have no clue look it up in the API documentation http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Core.Configure.html#_load and http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#reading-and-writing-configuration-files "but I still get errors." - What errors? **always** report error messages! Class constants: In the class / namespace where they fit in the best.

Comment: Updated my question with error message. But I am more interested with your answer about using Configure::load and using class constants. Can elaborate more?

Comment: can you update your answer so I can mark as correct? the solution is to add `use Cake\Core\Configure;` at the top of constants.php.